# Print the non-Ascii column value, python- spark

Tags: python, pyspark, ascii

Pretty new to python and spark, I have written a udf to remove the non-ascii character if it is present in the string.

What is the most effective way to make it print the erroraneous value along with doing the operation? ( Error values would be cells that contain non-ascii characters)

code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import pandas as pd
sc = spark.sparkContext

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, col
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def nonasciitoascii(unicodestring):
   return unicodestring.encode("ascii","ignore")

df=spark.read.csv("abc.csv")
df.show()

df.printSchema()

convertedudf = udf(nonasciitoascii)
converted = df.select('_c1','_c2').withColumn('converted',convertedudf(df._c1))
    converted.show()
```

Comment: What is the erroneous value here? Write an example of it, please.

Comment: the error values are the cells that contain non-ascii @OmG

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution which works for most of the time is running the computation for the purpose:

```
# in python 3
def check_ascii(string):
    if(not string.isascii()):
        return string
    else:
        return None

def check_ascii_in_python_2(string):
     if(not all(ord(char) < 128 for char in string)):
         return string
     else:
         return None

all_strings_with_non_ascii_chars = df.select('_c1','_c2').withColumn('check', check_ascii(df._c1)).filter('check is not null').select('check')
all_strings_with_non_ascii_chars.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @OmG, but i get   File "/opt/apps/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/csvparser.py", line 28, in check_ascii
    if(not string.isascii()):
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isascii'

 at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:83)